# two different URI mapping same view, one works well, however css can not be loaded for the other one

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

There are two methods with different URI which mapping to the same view in spring boot, the first one works well, however, the second one can only display html and css can not be loaded, the code is as below:

```
@Controller
public class ExamController {
    @RequestMapping("/quiz0")
    public ModelAndView quizingA() {
        System.out.println("run into quiz0");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("examination");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/quiz1/{course}")
    public ModelAndView quizingB(@PathVariable("course") String course) {
        System.out.println("run into quiz1, couse choosed: " + course);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("examination");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

From the log, both of them are reached successfully, as I known, there shouldn't be error existed, right?

For the first one which works well the url I used is;

```
http://localhost:8080/quiz0
```

For the second one which failed the url I used is:

```
http://localhost:8080/quiz1/Java
```

One more information, I have disabled spring security with override WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I can paste it out if required.

Could anyone help to explain it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to open up your browser's network console and check what the responses are for the HTTP requests for the CSS.

Comment: what is filtering (and not allowing) CSS, configure that Filter, Servlet to allow it

Comment: @JigarJoshi I config that with `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll();` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok, I'll have a try.

Comment: then probably it is not filtering it, can you debug the http request all the way from browser to server and each points on server

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis All the css and js files get error like `GET http://localhost:8080/quiz1/css/global/icheck/demo/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) `, but for the first controller(`quizingA()`), no error happened

Comment: @JigarJoshi All the css and js files get error like `GET http://localhost:8080/quiz1/css/global/icheck/demo/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) `, but for the first controller(`quizingA()`), no error happened

Comment: can you debug the http request all the way from browser to server and each points on server

Comment: Your css is generally in 1 location not 2… I suspect that your URLs differ and that you use the wrong URIs to retrieve the css. I suspect you use relative instead of absolute URIs.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for comment, the URIs what I use is relative path which following [http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security]

Comment: @M.Deinum Seems I misunderstand your meaning, when I change it to absolute URIs, it works, anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably including your css with a relative path instead of an absolute one.

e.g.
if you include like this

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The paths will be converted to

```
/quiz0/css/bootstrap.css
```

and

```
/quiz1/{course}/bootstrap.css
```

I recommend using it with absolute path

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Great work, it works after I change the view as you said. Thanks for saving my efforts.